# Java Regex Match If not preceded by keyword

Tags: java, regex

This is a regex specific question..

I need a regex that can find a certain keyword.. Example **ABCDE**
But it should not match if certain characters precede this keyword.. Example **]]**

So... In a line like this, it should only match the bold part..

[[TestChannel]] ABCDE: this is a test **ABCDE**

EDIT:
I have been trying things out here..
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

So far what i have tried..

```
(!]])(ABCDE)
((!]])ABCDE)
(!]])!(ABCDE)
((!]])|ABCDE)
```

**Solution**:
With help from the link Pshemo commented ->
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind

```
(?<!]])ABCDE
```

Comment: Hi Prathamesh, what have you tried? As you'll see, StackOverflow is not a place to delegate you work (the "I need" bit in your question).

Comment: Hi, sorry for not adding more info earlier.. Edited them in the questions.. I'll google more till then..
I had tried a few, but they didn't work.. I been trying to help a certain group of moderators in a community to setup their chat filters to find a specific list of keywords..

Comment: You probably want [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism, but read also about its [limitations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind).

Answer (score 8):

```
(?<!]])ABCDE
```

Thanks Pshemo for the links.

Comment: Could you please add this to answer to your original question? This would make it easier for others to quickly find your solution.